# PHP - Directory browsing from recursive to iterative

Tags: php, recursion, iteration

Hello I am trying to make the following function iterative. It browses threw all directories and gives me all files in there.

```
function getFilesFromDirectory($directory, &$results = array()){
    $files = scandir($directory);

    foreach($files as $key => $value){
        $path = realpath($directory.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$value);
        if(!is_dir($path)) {
            $results[] = $path;
        } else if($value != "." && $value != "..") {
            getFilesFromDirectory($path, $results);
            $results[] = $path;
        }
    }
    return $results;
}
```

I am sure that it is possible to make this function iterative but I really    have no approach how I can do this.

Comment: I doubt so. Directory tree is a tree. You don't know how deep it is beforehand.

Comment: Definitely possible, see my answer.

Comment: It is impossible without moving the push/pop operation from a recursive function call to a data structure - i.e. you can make the code iterative (at some cost) but not the operation. What are you trying to achieve by doing this?

Comment: @Jparkinson: no - this just hides the recursion behind an object - that's why you can't call the class statically.

Comment: But does it not achieve what the question author wants? Recursion through a directory returning all paths of files within it?

Comment: What I am searching for, is a way to have my function iterative instead of recursive.
@symcbean it does not really matter if this function hides the recursion behind an object, I just want to avoid a recursion in my code.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Still: What are you trying to achieve by doing this?

Comment: I preferably do not like recursive functions that are written by my own (they could result in an infinite loop for whatever reason; bad code, corner cases, etc..).
Also iterative functions are faster then recursive ones (what does not matter in this case, because it still does an recursive call in the background).

I am trying to achieve no recursive calls in my code; at least if I do not see them :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your going to want to use a few PHP base classes to implement this.

Using a **RecursiveDirectoryIterator** inside of a **RecursiveIteratorIterator** will allow you to iterate over everything within a directory regardless of how nested.

Its worth noting when looping over the **$iterator** below each **$item** is an object of type **SplFileinfo**. Information on this class can be found here: http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfileinfo.php

```
<?php 

//Iterate over a directory and add the filenames of all found children
function getFilesFromDirectory($directory){
    //Return an empty array if the directory could not be found
    if(!is_dir($directory)){
        return array();
    }

    $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
        new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($directory)
    );

    $found = array();
    foreach($iterator as $item){
        if(method_exists($item, 'isFile') && $item->isFile()){
            //Uncomment the below to exclude dot files
            //if(method_exists($item, 'isDot') && $item->isDot()){
            //  continue;
            //}
            
            //Pathname == full file path
            $found[] = $item->getPathname();
        }
    }

    return $found;
}
```

An var_dump of some found files i did using this function as a test:

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Approved! Thanks for your help @JParkinson1991.